# ASP Identity Role Does Not Exist Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to create a page in my MVC .NET CORE application in which a user can change the roles of other users. At this point the view and model bindings all work great, but when actually trying to save the roles back to the database I am getting an error saying that the roles don't exists. My approach is this:

1. Get list of roles from the model.
2. Delete existing roles for specified user.
3. Add roles back using list from model.
4. Do this all in a transaction in case of error.

My code in the controller is as follows:

```
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }

                using (_context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var removeResult = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user));
                    if (!removeResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return View("Error");
                    }

                    var addResult = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, model.MemberRoles);
                    if (!addResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return View("Error");
                    }
                }
```

Where `model.MemberRoles` as a `List<string>` of roles. The strange part is is that this process is failing on `_userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync`, even though I am passing the existing roles of the user directly into the function. I have tried ditching the `UserManager` class and going with ef but had no luck. I also verified that the roles in the model match what is in the database. Is there anything obviously wrong that would cause this to fail? Thanks.

**Edit**

Here is the error I am running into:

```
InvalidOperationException: Role ADMINISTRATOR does not exist.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4.<AddToRoleAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

And here are the roles defined in my database:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you try to add a user to a role, it first tries to find the role.  In Sql Profiler, you can see that it is actually searching by the NormalizedName field rather than the Name field.

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT TOP(2) [r].[Id], [r].[ConcurrencyStamp], [r].[Name], [r].[NormalizedName]
FROM [AspNetRoles] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[NormalizedName] = @__normalizedRoleName_0',N'@__normalizedRoleName_0 nvarchar(256)',@__normalizedRoleName_0=N'ADMINISTRATOR'
```

The solution is to set the NormalizedName field to the Uppercase of the Name field when you create the Roles:

So in the SeedData class:

```
/* Create Roles */
IEnumerable<UserRole> allRoles = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)).Cast<UserRole>();


foreach (UserRole role in allRoles)
{
     if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.ToString()))
     {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { 
                          Name = role.ToString(), 
                          NormalizedName = role.ToString().ToUpper() 
                        });
     }
}
```

Comment: This was my problem too.  My solution for existing roles was to run the sql `UPDATE [Roles] SET NormalizedName = UPPER(Name)`

Comment: I am getting red squiggly lines under  `roleManager`

Comment: Where does roleManager come from?

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised you're not getting an `InvalidCastException` instead, as it's not possible to directly cast `string[]` to `List<string>`. Not really sure why you're doing it that way in the first place, since you could just as easily just call `.ToList()`, instead of `.ToArray()`, and call it a day, if you want a list. Or, since the return type of `GetRolesAsync` is `IList<string>`, anyways, you don't even really need to do that. Right now, that's the only problem I see with your code, though.

Comment: I suppose you're right that was kind of weird. I updated my post to reflect those changes, however I am still seeing that the role doesn't exist.